# What is meant by "I had to invent new rules"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, person-of-interest

In Person of Interest episode YHWH (Season 4 finale), there is a heartbreaking dialogue between Finch and the machine, where the machine states

> I had to invent new rules.

What exactly is meant by this "rules"? Is it the fact that the machine wants them to kill the congress man in Season 3? Is it the fact that the machine sold herself to Samaritan in order to save her team? Or is it something else?

Comment: Have you watched all the seasons ?

Comment: @Panther Yes, I have. Maybe I have missed or forget a clear reference, but the statement within this dialogue seems too vague for me to clearly identify the "rules" the maschine means.

Comment: I suggest re-watching "If-Then-Else"; I think the rules she means are the ones Finch taught her while teaching her chess. All lives were to be considered equally important -- but then she had to sacrifice herself in the name of Finch and Co.

Comment: @Chiffa Oh, yeah! That's it! This is also directly connected to this episode. You shold post this as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest re-watching "If-Then-Else"; I think the rules she means are the ones Finch taught her while teaching her chess. All lives were to be considered equally important -- but then she had to sacrifice herself in the name of Finch and Co.